# Why are edits sometimes declined by Community, yet a similar edit shows up as accepted?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I have edited questions a couple of times, and will get rejected by Community (user -1) and will look at the question and it will contain the edits that I suggested.  Is it a race condition possibly based on someone else editing the file at the same time?

Once, I figured it out, it was someone rejecting it, but another person taking my edits and proposing the same edit.  (I talked with the editor, and this is the case.)

I find it strange behavior.  And it doesn't happen often, but when it happens, The times that I have noticed it, other than the one I talked to the editor) they have had a 3k+ reputation.

But it also counts as a 'reject' even though the changes were ultimately accepted due to the result, though not the mechanism.

Comment: Do you have to link to such suggested edit or post?

Comment: I figured someone would ask.  I only have one example, as it happened recently and is the one on my mind.  The [suggested edit on my mind](http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/53806)

Comment: I'd think that to be the only one, as it mentions `vgoff had 10 edit suggestions approved, and 1 edit suggestion rejected`. Anyhow, comparing this to the actual edit that happened on the post it appears they are different. So, the chance is high that the other editor was editing the post while you submitted your suggestion; thus rendering your suggested edit as rejected since another edit happened. I don't know though whether this is supposed to happen, when two editors work simultaneously this usually gives a warning of some kind when the second editor tries to submit.

Comment: It isn't the only one, just the only one on this site.  Which obviously is the site that we are concerned with.  About the simultaneous edit, I had noticed on other sites that the edit link just doesn't work.  So probably a 'race' condition for that to be excluded as an active link.  It is what I was thinking.  (And yes there are differences, though the ideas were similar.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 cases where I've seen this happen -

- A race condition when the edit suggested and a 2k+ user edited the post *simultaneously*. Since edits by 2k+ users don't have to be peer-reviewed, their edit gets priority & the system accepts the edit, rejecting other suggested edits
- The person who reviewed the edit unticked "Suggested edit was useful". In this case, the system incorporates the edits into the current revision, but since the tickbox was unchecked, the edit credit gets rejected

Comment: Thanks.  I knew it was the mechanism that was confusing me.  So basically do the edits off site, and then quickly paste them in to avoid some of the rejects?  Perhaps that ratio is unimportant.  I can't see your statistics, for example for accept/reject ratio.

Comment: @vgoff whether you do edits off site or on the site is irrelevant, the  race condition is when you submit the edit & the other user edits at the same. No amount of off-site editing can get around that.

Comment: I know what you mean, but this usually seems to happen when I take my time and have pressed the edit button, and then perhaps 10 minutes has one by.  I don't notice that I would normally not have the edit button... so it might cut it down a little bit.  Though not completely.  So perhaps only on one end of the deal.  Definitely not for the time between approval and someone 2k+ coming and editing.